# jquery on click function runs two time

Tags: jquery, ajax

an anchor tag dynamically appended and when clicked, it open a form to update data. but when click on next anchor tag, form submit runs two and more.

```
 $(document).on("click", ".edit_edu", function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    var edu_row_id = $(this).parents('.edu_rows').find('#edu_row_id').text();
    UIkit.modal('#edit_edu_course',function () {}).show();

   $('#educational_edit_records_form').submit(function () {
        $(this).ajaxSubmit({
            url: '<?php echo base_url("Resume/update_karjoo_educational_info") ?>/'+edu_row_id,
            resetForm:true,
            success: function () {
                UIkit.modal('#edit_edu_course').hide();
                UIkit.notification('well done!',{status:'primary',pos: 'bottom-right',timeout: 3000});
            },
            fail: function () {
                UIkit.notification('try again!',{status:'danger',pos: 'bottom-right',timeout: 3000});
            }
        });
        return false;
    });

});

 UIkit.util.on('#new_edu_course','hide',function () {
   $('#edu_list').empty();
    $.getJSON('<?php echo base_url('Resume/get_edu_fields/'.$cu_username)?>', function (response) {
        $.each(response,function (key,val) {
            $('<li class="edu_rows">'+'<span class="uk-hidden" id="edu_row_id">'+val.id+'</span>'+'<small class="uk-label uk-label-success">'+val.grade+'</small>'+'<span uk-icon="icon:chevron-right"></span>'+'<small class="uk-text-bold">'+val.field_name+'</small>'+'<span uk-icon="icon:chevron-right"></span>'+'<small class="uk-text-bold">'+val.uni_type+'</small>'+'<span uk-icon="icon:chevron-right"></span>'+'<small class="uk-text-bold">'+val.uni_name+'</small>'+'<ul class="uk-iconnav uk-float-left">'+'<li>'+'<button type="button" uk-tooltip="title:ویرایش" class="uk-text-warning edit_edu" uk-icon="icon: file-edit"></button>'+'</li>'+'<li>'+'<button type="button" uk-tooltip="title:حذف" class="uk-text-danger del_edu" uk-icon="icon: trash"></button>'+'</li>'+'</ul>'+'</li>').appendTo('#edu_list');
        })
    })
});
```

Comment: It's because you're nesting the `submit` event handler within the `click` handler. Therefore every time you click you're adding another `submit`. Do not do that. Move the `submit` handler *outside* the click. If you've done this because the element is dynamically created, use a delegated event handler instead.

Comment: thanks a lot. but when i move it, form not working.

Comment: oh my god!!! works! when define a global variable it works. thanks verrry much. i realy thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You are having 2 elements with the classname 'edit_edu' .

which would explain it.
check:

```
$('.edit_edu').length
```

Comment: oh sorry! yes. they appending into li tag. and i get id of them and send to controller. if needs, i put test website.

Comment: You apply the click eventhandler to ALL elements with classname 'edit_edu' !

Comment: thanks. jquery code that generate code added and updated question.